# FormsAuthentication: Whats the difference between Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER") and User.Identity.Name?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a feeling that `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` and `User.Identity.Name` return the same string while using `FormsAuthentication.`

So my question is as simple as that. Which one should i better use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They return the same value indeed, the ServerVariables is there only for backward compatibility with legacy code. Normally you should user `User.Identity.Name`.